# Javascript navigate with payload

Tags: javascript, http

An HTTP request can hold a payload not necessarily coming from an HTML form. I mean not being in the classical key/value format.

I would like to achieve that in JavaScript : when the user clicks on a button, a function is invoked that will issue an HTTP PUT request with text payload.

XMLHttpRequest does not seem to allow the complete page reload of the page when receiving the server answer. 
On the other hand, JavaScript Navigate method does not allow payload addition.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to send a text payload, rather than text as a value in an application/x-www-form-urlencoded form?

Comment: My need comes from the fact I invoke a server CGI expecting plain payload, not a key/value pair

Comment: Can't jQuery do this. I seem to remember sending pure json with jquery, so I imagine you can send pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a hidden `<form>` tag with `<input>`s containing your payload, then `submit()` it.

Comment: Thanks but is it not mandatory to set "name" attributes to input tags that will create a key/ value pair which I want to avoid ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the PUT verb, then XMLHttpRequest is your only option. You cannot do a PUT with a hidden (or non-hidden) form, and you cannot set the content-transfer-encoding using a form either.

However, when the XMLHttpRequest succeeds, you can use the Document Object Model to change the contents of the page based on what the server returns.

So for example, you could remove all the existing elements, and replace them with the HTML returned by the server. Or you could redirect the user to a different page.

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit unclear in my description but what I actually want is invoking an HTTP PUT request with payload leading to sole other location. Just like submitting a form or clinking on a link.

Comment: @user1474829, submitting a form doesn't use PUT. It uses either POST or GET.